# Build a website which allows image/video submissions via smartphone

Tags: php, android, html, mobile

I am trying to build a website which allows uploading of images and videos from a normal browser.  This portion is easy.  The tricky part which I am unfamiliar with is allowing mobile users to submit images/videos.  The goal is for a mobile user to easily upload the image. Any ideas/suggestions on how to tackle this?  Thanks!

*I should mention I already have a functioning website that allows image/video uploads using simple html file form.  Also, I am using PHP to develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very difficult as you may think.
There are several approaches to this:

1) You can build a mobile version for your website that fits mobile screen.
2) Build a webservice and doing a post form request from your mobile application(e.g Android).

You can have a look at mobile version to get the idea behind this.

[Android: Sending an image through POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397076/android-sending-an-image-through-post/9397239#comment11873691_9397239)

Comment: Would this allow for the mobile user to snap a photo and easily upload it?

Comment: Yes. Sure. I'm building an application allow user to select a number of image from Android Galary and post all of them to app engine server. You can do it easily by changing it a bit in order to get image from camera

Comment: Interesting, does the android gallery open up as soon as you hit browse?  Or is this something you have to code into the html / js?

Comment: Sorry. I missed your point. I'm talking about native Android app. If you are building a web version, I think as soon as you select the file. It will open up the file manager/gallery

Comment: sidenote: I'm pretty sure ios will not give a file browser for upload fields in the browser

Comment: unfortunately i do not have access to ios so testing this will be difficult.

Comment: J_syk is right. However they said it can be done via phonegap. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app.

Comment: Thanks Cuong, that looks like a very relevant conversation!